Angular app returns 404 on domain despite running fine in Docker container with Traefik
I'm a beginner setting up a continuous deployment pipeline for a Java Angular web application using Docker, Traefik, and GitHub Actions. I've successfully deployed my app on a VPS (Debian 12) with Portainer and configured Traefik to manage HTTPS via Let's Encrypt.
I purchased a domain through Cloudflare, and everything seems to be set up correctly. My Traefik setup handles HTTP to HTTPS redirection, and I can access my server over HTTPS. However, when I deploy my Angular app to the domain, I consistently receive a 404 error, even though the app is running fine inside the Docker container.
Here’s what I have configured:

Traefik Stack:

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=myemail@example.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=myemail@example.com
      - CF_API_KEY=${CLOUDFLARE_TOKEN}
    volumes:
      - "traefik-certificates:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      - web
    restart: always

networks:
  web:
    external: true

volumes:
  traefik-certificates:



Angular App Stack:

services:
  front:
    image: mydockerimage:latest
    container_name: angular-front
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.angular.rule=Host(`exemple.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.angular.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.angular.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
  watchtower:
    container_name: watchtower
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    environment:
      - WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --interval 60 angular-front

networks:
  web:
    external: true



Cloudflare:


DNS:
A record: Points to my VPS IP (Proxied via Cloudflare)
AAAA record: IPv6 address for the domain (Proxied via Cloudflare)
CNAME record: www subdomain pointing to the root domain (Proxied via Cloudflare)

-SSL/TLS:
Full (not strict)

Tests and Results:


Running curl http://localhost:80 inside the Angular container returns the correct HTML content, indicating the app is running as expected.

Accessing the domain via https://exemple.com results in a 404 error.


Expected Result:
I expected to see my Angular app served on my domain.
Actual Result:
I consistently receive a 404 error when trying to access the app through the domain.
What could be causing this 404 error, and how can I resolve it? As I'm new to this, I'd appreciate any straightforward advice.

Note that in your current config you are exposing the traefik dashboard publicly to the Internet on port 8080! You really should limit this to a local port only and/or put some form of authorization in front of it

@arcan Ok thanks !

Your angular container seems to use the traefik entrypoint web which is the plain HTTP on port 80.
So http://exemple.com/ should be working. To make secure HTTPS work instead change the entrypoint of the service:
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.angular.entrypoints=websecure"


@arcan
Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I tried both of the following configurations: "traefik.http.routers.angular.entrypoints=websecure" "traefik.http.services.angular.loadbalancer.server.port=80" And "traefik.http.routers.angular.entrypoints=websecure" "traefik.http.services.angular.loadbalancer.server.port=443" However, I'm still receiving a 404 error.

note that traefik.http.services.angular.loadbalancer.server.port needs to point at the port on the service container, i.e., the port your angular application is running on!
